# Positive word for someone who wants to get into relationships with rich people

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I think *opportunist* would be the word for someone who wants to get into relationships with rich people so that they can get rich, but that word is negative and can be used for other situations as well. Do we have a more accurate word for it?

Comment: Honestly, I think opportunist is much more positive than the other word I can think of... gold-digger,

Comment: What is the etymological origin of the use of the phrase "gold-digger" to mean a relationship-wise opportunistic person? I think it originated in idioms that existed for hundreds of years in east asia.

Comment: *Upwardly mobile"

Comment: Why would you look for a positive word for something so inherently negative? "*So that they can get rich*" as the reason to frequent someone wealthy? And you want to put a positive spin on that? Why?

Comment: **inherently negative?**  what country do you live in (if you don't mind my asking).  I can't imagine anyone making the most important life, family and business decision (marriage) without considering their partner's education, achievements, whether they are perhaps massively in debt, have a job, rich, not rich, etc ...can you imagine someone getting married in a kind of .. abstract .. way because of ... actually because of what?  **physical looks**?  I can't even fully parse the concept.

Comment: note too that political views have no place at all on a language site, for goodness sake. The OP is looking for a certain word, you don't even know her intended use case.

Comment: As Catja says "opportunistic" is not necessarily negatve.  Simply read the greatest novel in English for a full investigation in to the subtleties of emotion and social issues surrounding women marrying "for money".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ***[social climber](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/social+climber)***  may suggest the idea and doesn't necessarily have negative connotations:

> - a person who attempts to gain a higher social standing.
> - a person who tries to gain acceptance to a social stratum above the one he or she currently occupies.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: But OP specified getting into relationships, which is why Catija suggested a worse word. Social climbing is not so much about bed as about addresses, children's schools, clothes and so forth. It's not even about getting rich as much as about perceptions.

Comment: well, social climbing refers to the ambitious efforts to move up the social ladder, where rich people usually are.

Comment: Social hierarchy is not only determined by wealth. Though the latter has an undoubted part to play, there is often tension between the ideas of wealth and social elitism. Our language can reflect this.

Comment: Yes, but social climbing has a lot to do with money, in my opiniom.

Comment: @Josh61 I agree.

Comment: And there is the concept of *striver* as in [*Strivers' Row*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Nicholas_Historic_District), nicknamed for those who worked hard to better themselves and live in more elegant housing.

Comment: this (a) is unrelated to relationships, (b) is always negatively used.

Comment: @Joe, I would say *social climber* is predominantly negative, but not always, and and the word [*social*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/social) speaks directly to a network of relationships.

Comment: "social climber" has little or no relationship to marriage.  the answer is (no offence Josh) pointless.   you can trivially look up usages of and a definition of "social climber" if unfamiliar with it; David expressed it perfectly.

Comment: @Joe - I think the term can fit the context presented by OP quite nicely and is less generic than other suggested options. OP seems to find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

*[Ambitious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambitious)* is suitable:

> adjective
>
> 1 Having or showing a strong desire and determination to succeed:

If your measure of success is wealth, then hooking up with a rich person seems like a reasonable strategy. Like the OP and other answers provided, it can elicit either positive or negative connotations, and it can easily be applied to various situations. The history of *[ambitious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambitious&allowed_in_frame=0)* connects it firmly to the notion of relationships:

> (adj.)   late 14c., from Latin *ambitiosus* "going around to canvass for
>   office,"   from *ambitio* (see *[ambition](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambition&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>
> mid-14c., from Middle French *ambition* or
>   directly from
>   *ambitionem* (nominative *ambitio*) "a going around," especially to solicit votes,
>   hence "a striving for favor, courting, flattery; a
>   desire for honor, thirst for popularity,"
>   noun of action from past
>   participle stem of ambire "to go around" (see *ambient*).

Answer (score 1):

As you say "gold digger" is wholly negative, and is often used, by for example, people who foolishly married badly with no regard to education, economic status etc.

I don't have a more accurate term (as you ask) which is neutral.

However, there are two terms which are commonly used in this situation. These are "practical" and "sensible".

```
She was very practical about marriage.
```

Note: as Scott has pointed out, add "ambitious" to this list.

These three words CAN BE used in a straight, neutral way.  "My daughter made a sensible marriage." "Fortunately Annie made a practical marriage instead of getting pregnant at 17 to that boy with the motorbike."

However, note that indeed the three terms can be used "with a wink" as euphemisms, to imply the same sort of gold-digger-language disapproval.

(I mean all of this in typical AmE or BrE ...  of course in many countries arranged marriage, etc., is the norm and it would seem bizarre to marry for purely emotional reasons.)

Comment: Practical is a too generic term...

Comment: It seems to me the euphemism "practical" is a positive way to express this concept, but the context would have to set the stage for this meaning.

Comment: Hi Josh, it's very common to use that term to describe such a person. It's exactly the word used "in air-quotes" in the situation.

Comment: GoodAM - excellent point, like a euphemism

Comment: Your answer is focused on a woman making a practical choice before deciding to marry someone, but the OP never mentions marriage, he asks about someone who wants to have *relationships with* wealthy people. You've interpreted the question a little too narrowly. ScotM's answer is closer, but  I don't particularly like any of the answers posted so far

Comment: HI Mari-Lou -- there must be a misunderstanding: in my comments and answers I specifically excoriated people who assume this is some sort of bad thing! pls reread.  And thanks for pointing out I was not clear enough, I will edit  :)

Comment: I read (a) as your confirmation/approval that a woman who marries a wealthy man can be said to be a gold digger. It is *sometimes* true, but marriage is not the only venue, and mixing in the right circles in order to gain important and influential contacts, is not unbeknown to enterprising men and women.

Comment: I think it's remarkably common in real life that men chase rich women, for no other reason than money, as a pure monetary gain approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP is looking for a *positive* word, may I suggest a **pragmatist**

> someone who is pragmatic, that is to say, someone who is practical and focused on reaching a goal. [A pragmatist usually has a straightforward, matter-of-fact approach and doesn't let emotion distract her](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pragmatist).

or an **enterprising** individual:

> having or showing initiative and resourcefulness.

It's worth noting that two users assumed the OP was referring to a category of women whose sole objective is to offer sexual favours in return for money, or to marry a wealthy man. While no one is denying this does happen; it is, as Joe Blow clearly stated in his answer, a very *practical* approach to improving one's economic status; men are not immune to using sex as a means of obtaining prosperity.  [**Gigolos**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gigolos)

> 1. A man who has a continuing sexual relationship with and receives financial support from a usually older woman

and **[toy boys](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toy+boy)**

> 1. the much younger male lover of an older woman

are but two  (usually derogatory) expressions, reserved for men who *consciously* exploit their youth, and physical appearance in order to receive generous financial rewards.

But for *anybody* who has no discernible talent, lacks qualifications and a strong work ethic, they will look at marriage with a critical and **objective eye**.   Youth and physical beauty are inexorably intertwined, a **pragmatic** and **determined** individual knows that time is of essence, and will attempt to snare their ‘prey’ before they have reached their forties. In addition, many view that  marriage is synonymous with a "business contract", there are [prenups](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/personal-finance/engaged-couples-sign-prenup-1.aspx) which must be signed by both parties before a marriage can be undertaken.

> Any couple who brings personal or business assets to the marriage can benefit from a *prenup*. The most basic of these **contracts** lists an inventory of premarital *assets* that in the event of a divorce will remain the property of their original owner.

Conversely, I would say a person who wishes to mix in the right circles, which often include affluent people; celebrities; business men and women; in order to widen their social contacts and build a ‘profitable’ network, is an **enterprising** and **[astute](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/astute)** **individual**.

> 1. of keen penetration or discernment; sagacious:
>      *an astute analysis.*
> 2. clever; cunning; ingenious; shrewd:

This type of pragmatism is deeply ingrained, especially in Europe

> Almost two thirds believe that **social connections are still more important than “what you know”** in determining how people advance in life, it found. […] 
>   Just over than three quarters of those polled said they believed family background significantly influences an individual's chances of doing well in life. And 65 per cent agreed that fundamentally "who you know matters more than what you know" in Britain today.
>
> <sup>Source: [The Daily Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/10137928/Its-still-who-you-know-not-what-you-know-that-matters-say-two-thirds-of-Britons.html)</sup>

The mantra

> It's not what you know, but **who you know**
>   <sup>[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27s_not_what_you_know_but_who_you_know)</sup>

is as true today in the 21st century as it was in the 20th.